# Find a random string in NSMutableString

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutablestring

I have seen a lot of q&a on how to generate random strings.  But what about the case where I have an array of strings (perhaps thousands) and I want to grab a random string so a different one is presented to the user each time?  Thanks in advance.

```
wordsArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
[wordsArray objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform([wordsArray count])];
```

provided that the array is not empty.

**Updated:** use `arc4random_uniform()` for better stability. (Thanks Richard)

Comment: Use `arc4random_uniform()` instead, as that is more stable than the modulus method.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Thanks Richard. What makes it more stable?

Comment: `arc4random_uniform() will return a uniformly distributed random number
     less than upper_bound.  arc4random_uniform() is recommended over con-
     structions like 'arc4random() % upper_bound' as it avoids "modulo bias"
     when the upper bound is not a power of two.
` from the man page for [arc4random()_uniform](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/3/arc4random_uniform/)

Comment: Hi Sooper,  Is that intended to return a value?  I must not be using quite correctly.  Please update if you can.